# Border collapsing between nth column element

Tags: html, css

This is the code snippet. I want to implement 0 spacing between the nth and n-1th element, I tried using left and right as zero between the adjacent child but that doesn't work as well.

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 10px 5px;
}

th {
  text-align: left;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 0 5px;
  height: 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}
td:nth-child(3)
{
  left:0;
}
td:nth-child(2)
{
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Exams</th>
    <th>Science</th>
    <th>Mathematics</th>
    <th>Biology</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2000</td>
    <td>95</td>
    <td>64</td>
    <td>33</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What I want is to reduce the gap between the second and third element of td to be zero, that's it.

I want zero gap between 95 and 64.

Comment: The spacing is being added by `table { border-spacing: 10px 5px; }`. You can't change border-spacing for individual cells, nor can table cells have margins, so you will have to restructure your code. You could use CSS grids instead of a table, use `display:table` or possibly even just create coloured divs inside the cells to contain the text, which would allow you to add margins.

Comment: Hmm, actually I am not allowed to alter HTML or JS part, all changes I can make is in CSS part.

Comment: Is this just for a project or is it work for a real site? If its project work, I can give you a hack that might work but I definitely wouldn't recommend using it for real...

Comment: It's for a real site, apache-superset. Actually, I have some other hacks too but what I wanted is a clean way for setting border spacing for certain cells, I thought we could somehow do it with css. Btw what hack are you talking about would love to know!

Comment: Not when it comes to HTML tables - you can't set margins of border spacing on individual cells so you would have to change the html. The hack was using borders rather than border spacing - its'd definitely a hack but the only way in CSS that AFAIK

Comment: I see, hmm thanks anyways! Will try to do something else :-)